# How to add object into nested state in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate, react-state

I'm creating simple comment box where user can reply on comment . I have defined state as follows :

```
  this.state = {
       comments: [
            {
                id: "TKT4321",
                message: "abc",
               
            },
            {
                id: "TKT34341",
                message: "cccccc",
                reply: [
                    { id: "TKT34343", message: "aaaaa" },
                ]
            },

        ],
        
    }
```

one object of **coments** is one comment and **reply** is user replied on that comment

```
          {
                id: "TKT34341",
                message: "cccccc",
                reply: [
                    { id: "TKT34343", message: "aaaaa" },
                ]
            },
```

what i want to do is when user replied on comment let's say on comment having id "TKT4321" then add **reply** object to that list . e.g

```
              {
                id: "TKT4321",
                message: "abc",
                 reply: [
                    { id: "TKT34343", message: "gfgfg" },
                ]
            },
```

If the replies are already there in the **reply** array then just append **{ id: "TKT341113", message: "ftrdgf" }** object to **reply** array. e.g

```
               {
                id: "TKT34341",
                message: "cccccc",
                reply: [
                    { id: "TKT34343", message: "aaaaa" },
                    { id: "TKT341113", message: "ftrdgf" },
                ]
            },
```

my soltuion is :

```
    this.setState((state) => {
        const { comments } = state.comments
        return comments.map((item) => ({
            ...item,
            reply: [...item.reply, { id: "TK2222", message: "jkjk" }]
        }))
    })
```

But with this i'm not able to set the state.
I'm new to react and i'm confused how to set the state of nested objects.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the comments as a new state, without the `comments` key, overwriting all state. Instead, do this:

```js
 this.setState((state) => {
        const { comments } = state.comments
        return {  // Add an object around the comments
            comments.map((item) => ({
                ...item,
                reply: [...item.reply, { id: "TK2222", message: "jkjk" }]
            }))
        };
    })
```